# Netbeans 8.0 Beta package with embeded j2me 8.0 javax.microedition.lcdui.* not found

Tags: java, java-me

I am new in j2me programming, I have installed Netbeans 8.0 Beta package with embeded j2me 8.0, I have started to create a mobile application but when importing javax.microedition.lcdui.*, there is an error the package  javax.microedition.lcdui.* not found.

Kindly help the soonest possible time. Thanking you in advance for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like a Netbeans Config problem. (also just a personal note, if possible install the release version of netbeans opposed to a beta. )

do you have a "j2me" platform installed in your netbeans installation

Even though I HATE Video tutorials, take a look at this:

https://netbeans.org/kb/docs/javame/nb_me_plugins_screencast.html

Should solve your issue,